# BitmapFactory decodeByteArray SkImageDecoder Factory returned null - image from JSON

Tags: java, php, android, json

I have a program with can login into the server throught PHP form (he fill the form with username and password) and then the PHP script generate a very simple JSON file:

```html
{
 "success":1,
 "message":"PHP Login successful!",
 "userid":"1",
 "data":
 [
  {
   "id_data":"1",
   "data_name":"Mona Lisa",
   "data_date":"29.9. 2015",
   "pic_user_id_user":"1",
   "data_picture":‰PNG

   
IHDR         Ä¾‹   sRGB ®Îé   gAMA  ±üa    pHYs  Ä  Ä•+   TIDAT(S]NÙ  b”FqtGqòªgýB °„¶„¨Ž5—ŽxB¼æÇ³A»ar
SHÞMÞÐæ5š7Ž†ÿÈ
Œ*Qæ92V¸pRÏªü(Ü 
…üZI÷Í    IEND®B`‚"
  },
 ]
}
```

thats all working, set TextView with name and date of image too. But when I want to draw image, logCat write error SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null. I dont want download image from any url, I just want draw image from JSON.
There is public method, when the login has been sucessfull and then set the public variables where are JSON data. Then in the next Fragment (list_of_files.java) use public variables (main.java) and write data on screen.

```
// main.java
public static void login_success(JSONObject login_json) throws JSONException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    status.setText("Login successful.");
    JSONArray data = login_json.getJSONArray("data");   // get array data witch contains all information about image
    int count_of_images = data.length();                // get count, how many images user have
    img_name = new String[count_of_images];             // then, create an array, with contains name of each image
    img_date = new String[count_of_images];             // and the date of image

    // {...} - JSONObject (work with normal methods getting value of coll, f.e. getString( "name of coll" )
    // [...] - JSONArray (work with index - numbers)
    for (int i = 0; i < count_of_images; i++){
        JSONObject under_data = data.getJSONObject(i);
        img_name[i] = under_data.getString("data_name");
        img_date[i] = under_data.getString("data_date");
        if ( i == 0 )
            img_img = under_data.getString("data_picture").getBytes();
    }
    Log.d("== IMAGE SIZE ==", String.valueOf(img_img.length) + " B");
}





// list_of_files.java
    // Update listView list_of_files
    if (list_of_files_str != null) {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_of_files_str);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            private FragmentManager supportFragmentManager;

            public FragmentManager getSupportFragmentManager() {
                return supportFragmentManager;
            }

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // set image name and date in textView
                TextView image_name = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.image_name);
                image_name.setText(list_of_files_str[position] + " // " + date_str[position]);

                // draw image with char array from main class Red Orchestra
                ImageView img = (ImageView)getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView);

                Bitmap image_to_draw;
                byte[] data;
                String str = "";
                try {
                    data = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
                    String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(base64.getBytes(), Base64.URL_SAFE);
                    image_to_draw = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                    img.setImageBitmap( image_to_draw );
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

    } else { // if the user is not login, write him message
        String[] must_login = new String[] {"You must be sign in."};
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, must_login);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}
```

I dont really know, how to save this problem. I searched throught different forums and websites, but nothing work.

PHP file:

```
//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
```

require("config.inc.php");
$login_ok = false;

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $query_1 = "SELECT * FROM pic_user WHERE user_name = :username";

```
$query_params = array(
    ':username' => $_POST['username']
);

try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query_1);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "PHP Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

$validated_info = false;

$row = $stmt->fetch();
if ($row) {
    if ($_POST['password'] === $row['user_password']) {
        $login_ok = true;
    }
}

if ($login_ok) {
    $query_2   = "SELECT * FROM pic_data WHERE pic_user_id_user = :userid";

    $user_id   = $row['id_user'];
    $user_name = $row['user_name'];

    $query_params_2 = array( ':userid' => $user_id );
    $stmt         = $db->prepare($query_2);
    $result       = $stmt->execute($query_params_2);
    $row          = $stmt->fetchAll();

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "PHP Login successful!";
    $response["userid"]  = $user_id;
    $response['data']    = $row;

    die(json_encode($response));

} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "PHP Invalid Credentials!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to send an image in JSON?  This is why we have mime types on flies so that you can let the browser handle this for you.

Comment: Who wrote the php file? Please show the code. It looks as the json contains the image bytes but i'm not shure. I did not know that that was possible.  If it does then 'img_img = under_data.getString("data_picture").getBytes();'. is wrong. You are first making a string out of those bytes and then convert the string back to bytes. That will introduce all kind of changes.

Comment: I added the PHP file under this comment. I just need i my app get image from server and then update and add new image to server. Thats all...

Comment: You did not react on all the things i said. You are supposed to do that to begin with.

Comment: Please put the whole php code in a code block. Don't make such a mess.

Comment: '  $row          = $stmt->fetchAll();'. We cannot see what you fetch. We nowhere see an image or the identifier names used in the Android code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve got it! There´s just wrong base64 convert. When I delete convertion in code and convert image to base64 (http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) and add base64 string into database and than download it throught JSON, it works.